# Node.JS Reduce CPU Load when Listener is Receiving Many Events

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, sequelize.js

My Node.js app has 3 event listeners that receive a total of 5-10k events every second. These listener functions involve sending INSERT queries to a PostgreSQL database. For example,

```
foo.on('msg', data => sequelize.create(some_processing(data)));
```

Running the node app on a cloud server with 1 vCPU and 1 GB of RAM, the server load is almost always 100%. After running for some time, the ORM will complain about connection timing out. My guess is that the function calls are being queued till it takes more than the timeout threshold for the database query to be made.

**Question:** Are the listener functions blocking? If so, will it help reduce CPU load by making it an asynchronous fire-and-foreget call, and how can this be done?

For my purpose, it is OK to insert the data out-of-order as every row inserted has a timestamp.

Running node.js app on first server

- node v12.14.0
- Ubuntu 18.04
- 1 vCPU, 1 GB RAM, 4 GB Swap, SSD

Running PostgreSQL on *second* server

- PostgreSQL 11.5
- Ubuntu 18.04 server
- 1 vCPU, 1 GB RAM, 4 GB Swap, SSD

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe a queue implementation like rabitmq in the DB layer will solver your problem

Comment: @iambatman The PostgreSQL database is hosted on a different server from the node.js app, so it should currently behave as if node.js is submitting to a queue like RabbitMQ/Kafka. Edited the question to made this clearer. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be curious how it would behave if you replaced sequalize.js and used eg. https://github.com/porsager/postgres directly which is faster, but also sends queries over the wire immediately.